# s3 path printed incorrectly by spark excel reader

Tags: excel, scala, apache-spark, spark-excel

I am trying to read an excel sheet from Amazon S3 and here is the code snippet. But it fails saying file doesn't exist though its there , I checked there is a slash (/) missing from the path.

```
println(path)
val data = sqlContext.read.
    format("com.crealytics.spark.excel").
    option("location", s3path).
    option("useHeader", "true").
    option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "true").
    option("inferSchema","true").
    option("addColorColumns", "true").
    load(path)
```

path is correctly printed as :
`s3a://AKIAJDDDDDDACNA:A6voquDDDDDqNOUsONDy@my-test/test.xlsx`

But why the slash is missing when read by spark? Here is the error message :

```
 Name: java.io.FileNotFoundException
    Message: s3a:/AKIAJYDDDDDDNA:A6DDDDDDDDDwqxkRqUQyXqqNOUsONDy@my-test/test.xlsx (No such file or directory)
    StackTrace:   at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
      at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:212)
      at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:152)
      at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:104)
      at com.crealytics.spark.excel.ExcelRelation.<init>(ExcelRelation.scala:28)
      at com.crealytics.spark.excel.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:31)
      at com.crealytics.spark.excel.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:7)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:345)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:149)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:122)
      at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:46)
      at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:46)
      at time(<console>:36)
```

Comment: You can obfuscate your aws credentials and show us the path you are giving to the reader ?

Comment: Should I paste the complete correct AWS S3 path here?

Comment: Hide your credentials and change the names of your buckets

Comment: yes, they are already masked

Comment: Is this a defect ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow the s3a URL is getting down to `java.io.FileInputStream.open()`, which only works with local filesystem files, not HDFS, S3, etc. You will need to track down what is happening there inside `com.crealytics.spark.excel`. Welcome to the word of using IDEs to work out what third party libraries get up to :) (IntelliJ IDEA is very good at that BTW, as it can go from a pasted stack trace to the specific source code)

Also: don't put your secrets in your URLs, that's dangerous & something which may get disabled in future for security reasons. Set `spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key` and `spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key` in your `spark-defaults.conf`.

Comment: Thanks for the response

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use the HadoopOffice library to read/write Excel files. It supports Spark datasources, but is also Hadoop native, so your s3 URL will probably work out of the box.

https://github.com/ZuInnoTe/hadoopoffice/wiki